What is the error in this sentence and what can be the improvement? "The view of the downstream and directly down the bridge was awesome."
This is a question of common error previously asked in UPSC NDA Examination which is conducted in India for recruitment of officers in the Indian Armed Forces.

The view was awesome. Good. But what is "downstream" and "directly down"?

This is not the place to ask of answers to your test questions. The addition of and does not sound quite correct to the British ear.

You can salvage the sentence a bit by removing "of the".

"The view downstream from the bridge was awesome." is grammatical and makes sense.
